# Expo web AuthSession error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

I am using [AuthSession](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) in my React Native Expo app to login with auth0 ([following this example](https://community.auth0.com/t/implementing-auth0-in-react-native-expo-app/17406/10)).

```
async mobileLogin(){
    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    ...
}
```

The login work fine with Android and iOS, when I use it on the Web the AuthSession module breaks with:

```
bundle.js:19465 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
```

Digging into the AuthSession Expo module, the code breaks at line 150 ([link to source code on github](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo/src/AuthSession.ts#L150)).
In the [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) AuthSession should be supported for Web, but for one of its dependencies [expo-app-auth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-auth/?redirected):

> Web support is planned to be added

My guess is that since expo-app-auth is not supported for Web, AuthSession breaks when used from Web (whereas working from mobile). Is this true? Should I instead look for another way to login with auth0 in my React Native app from the web? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to inform you that AuthSession is actually not available for web. [Check the doc page again](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) under "Platform Compatibility".

At the moment, Your best bet is [AppAuth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/app-auth/). It's [currently being ported to the web](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6883), so I recommend you keep an eye on it.

Comment: ok thanks, isn't there some hacky workaround at all? like using the react auth0 library "react-auth0-spa" beyond some `if (Platform.OS === "web")` condition? I am a RN/React n00b so I don't have too much familiarity

Comment: Haven't tried that, but I don't think you can do this... yet. So you're gonna have to rely on `Platform` for now.

Comment: what do you mean rely on Platform?

Comment: What I mean is, you're gonna have to disable this feature for the web for now, by checking the platform.

Comment: Yes, I did this with most my feature, the problem is this is the "login" feature so if I disabling this feature means I can't support the RN Web app and drop Expo for React :C

Comment: Well, it's only the oAuth feature, so my suggestion is to disable the oAuth login for web, allow people to login via Username/Email and password and let them know oAuth login is coming soon. Well that's only if you're allowed to be this flexible.